# Expression Value in Jasper Report: "Cannot cast from String to Boolean" error

Tags: java, jasper-reports

This is my expression code:

```
($F{Personel_ODEME}.equals(Boolean.TRUE)) ? "PAID" : "NO PAID"
```

If Personel is paid, her/his Jasper tax report will read `PAID`, otherwise `NO PAID`. In the DB, this field is Boolean type, but the expression is returning a String type. So I am getting a `Cannot cast from String to Boolean` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I fixed it. I changed `$F{Personel_ODEME}`'s type to String, then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

The problem stems from your test `$F{Personel_ODEME}.equals(Boolean.TRUE)`, which Jasper is thinking is a `String` to `Boolean` comparison, and doesnt like.  To fix this, try this:

```
($F{Personel_ODEME}.equals(Boolean.TRUE.toString())) ? "PAID" : "NO PAID"
```

This will result in a `String` to `String` comparison.

It is good to note that In Java, a `"true".equals(Boolean.TRUE)` would result to false.

**edit:**

This appears to be a Jasper 'PrintWhen' expression, which allows you to determine whether to print the contents of a cell or not.  It is expecting `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` as its return values.  When you return "PAID", Jasper tries to evaluate that `String` as a `Boolean`, which it cant, so it throws the exception.

Comment: I believe you mean - "true".equals(Boolean.TRUE)

Comment: nope this no fix my problem. $F{Personel_ODEME} is BOolean field i cant use toString method.Gettin same error.

Comment: I know what is the problem but how can i solve it ? Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the Class Expression for the field to java.lang.String as it will be java.lang.Boolean by default. When it evaluates your if and tries to return "PAID" or "NO PAID", the field tries to convert that to Boolean so it can be displayed.

All credit goes to:

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=61775

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Boolean.valueOf($F{Personel_ODEME}.equals('TRUE')) ? "PAID" : "NO PAID"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
($F{Personel_ODEME}==true?"PAID":"NO PAID")
```

Note: true(keyword) is case sensitive. And should not be capital(TRUE)